# How to include files in a cron job?

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I run a cron job on a MediaTemple (gs) hosting, the command is the following:

```
php5 /home/144061/data/test.php
```

Inside the php file, and include statement is located.

The cron job returns an error:

```
Warning: include(../domains/test.com/html/wp-blog-header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144061/data/delete_seen.php on line 3

Warning: include(): Failed opening '../domains/test.com/html/wp-blog-header.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/php-5.3.15/share/pear') in /nfs/c10/h02/mnt/144061/data/delete_seen.php on line 3
```

I want to be able to include wordpress header in my cron file so that I can use wordpress functions and database connection in my cron script, what's wrong with my include statement?

Comment: Can you verify the path and file-name are correct?

Comment: most likely the current working directory is set to '/home/144061' when your script is invoked as a cron task.

Comment: The paths need to be relative to the run directory of the cron, that's why the paths are currently invalid.

Comment: They are relative to the path, the two folders domains ad data are in the same directory.

Comment: Does the cron run successfully from the terminal?

Comment: Yes it does, the problem is that I can't include the file that's all.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved with `set_include_path('/path/to/my/folder/');`
and after
`include('my-script.php')`.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still struggling with this, please note that your include path must be relative to you CRON path run directory. Otherwise, it won't find the files you're trying to include. For example, in Cpanel, I used the following : `require('home/yourdomain/public_html/wp-load.php')`.

Also, instead of including the header, you should include `wp-load.php`, which includes all of the core Wordpress functionalities.